# Information matrix for a Student's T distribution

Tags: likelihood, fisher-information

I'm reading a paper from Creal, Koopman, Lucas "Univariate Generalized Autoregressive Score Volatility Models" and I'm stuck with this computation.

[image]

After considering the log likelihood, the score is obtained by differentiation. However, how do I get the negative of the inverse of the information Matrix as it is presented? I tried to differentiate another time the score w.r.t. $\sigma^2$ and then taking the expecation, but I don't know how to get the given result... Can anybody help me?

Comment: The last line is not the negative inverse information. It is just the inverse/reciprocal of the information. I checked the first derivative. It checks out. So take one more derivative of the second to last line, take the expectation, then take the negative, then take the reciprocal.

Comment: @Taylor It is not necessary to differentiate again: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Definition.

Comment: @whuber Yeah, but that's not the way that this cut-out seems to be doing it. You're referring to the alternative option of taking the second moment of the first derivative, right?

Comment: @Taylor Yes.  By not differentiating and noting that the expectation scales as $\sigma_t^{-4}$, one may simply omit $\sigma_t$ altogether in the calculation, which is a bit of a simplification.

Comment: @whuber oh yeah you're right, the $y_t$s disappear.

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't seem to get the whole story... I tried to take the expectation of the score, but I cannot make it vanish, since I don't know how to compute the expectation of $1/y^2_t$... Can anybody show me how to properly move through these passages?